# Sending Outlook email using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

This code is working in another Access db.

I just copy pasted the code but there is an error in the first line.

```
Public Function sendEmailOutlook()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
' Create the Outlook session.
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Create the message.
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objOutlookMsg
' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("sads")
'Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("niticin@gmail.com")
objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
.Subject = "This is an automatic confirmation"
.Body = "This is a confirmation of the" & Form_Booking.Event_Name.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "Client: " & Form_Booking.FirstName.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Start Time: " & Form_Booking.Actual_Start_Time.Value
.Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance
.Save
.Send
    
End With
'Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("Make sure your Outlook is active and configured!")
End Function
```

Error on line

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
```

> compiler : user defined type not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using early binding, so in the VBA Editor you need to click Tools -> References & tick *Microsoft Outlook ?? Object Library* in order to expose Outlook's object model to your code.